# What is the difference between a CryptoKeyStore and a Wallet in Hyperledger Fabric Node SDK?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Hyperledger Fabric Node SDK seems to have two classes that solves the same problem - Storing user identities. [CryptoKeyStore](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/CryptoKeyStore.html) and [Wallet](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/module-fabric-network.Wallet.html). Could you please explain the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Cryptostore is a repository for storing private keys (ie eg. where the users' keys are kept) and can be backed by different KeyValueStore implementations.

Wallets hold identities that are used by applications on behalf of users to access Fabric (blockchain network) resources, such as invoking a smart contract transaction in that user's (identity) context. There are different types of wallets available depending on your application and security needs (eg Filesystem, Cloud, HSM etc). More info on Wallets can be found here -> https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/developapps/wallet.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 

In my understanding, even before the release of wallets, fabric-client had the [user context](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/User.html) along with credential store implementation that could load user identities from the cryptokeystore and applications can use them to act on behalf of a user. Is it different in case of a wallet?

Am I missing something?